# drop shadow filter for internet explorer?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, filter

I have been trying to get a shadow working on explorer, I already have it working in chrome and mozilla but I cant on explorer. I have been trying code like this

```
<!-- Internet Explorer -->
    <!--[if IE]>   
    <style>
    #blur_min
    {
                filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.dropshadow(OffX=2, OffY=5, 
            Color='gray', Positive='true')
    }
    </style>
    <![endif]-->
```

Comment: use css3pie instead. http://css3pie.com

Comment: It needs to be a filter rather than the dropbox version for a project

Answer (score 0):

Use a box or text shadow in CSS, it works in all the browsers. Filters are legacy and very inefficient.

```
-webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px 2px #575757;
box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px 2px #575757;
```

Check out http://css3generator.com/ for help creating CSS.